# Not able to get a random int value from Random class

Tags: java, random, bukkit

i have this code;

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@EventHandler
public void entityShoot(EntityDeathEvent e) {
    ArrayList<ItemStack> drops = new ArrayList<ItemStack>();
    Random rand = new Random();
    int sword = rand.getInt(1) + 1;
    int chest = rand.getInt(9) + 1;
    if(sword == 1)
    {
      drops.add(new ItemStack(swordID));
    }
    if(chest == 1)
    {
      drops.add(new ItemStack(chestID));
    }
}
```

But there is a error in getInt.
If i change it to nextInt, there is no random..
Its for Minecraft Bukkit.
Can you correct the code?
I don´t understand..

Thank you!
Regards, René :)

Comment: `java.util.Random` works just fine. Have you read the javadoc?

Answer (score 3):

this

```
 int sword = rand.getInt(1) + 1;
 int chest = rand.getInt(9) + 1;
```

shall be

```
 int sword = rand.nextInt(1) + 1;
 int chest = rand.nextInt(9) + 1;
```

instead

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

`getInt()` is not a method, that will not even compile.

`nextInt()`'s parameter is exclusive so a call to `nextInt(1)` will always give you a zero.  That might be why it appears not to be random to you.

Also, instead of adding a 1 to chest and then checking to see if equals 1, just don't add anything and check for it to equal zero.  Same for sword.

Answer (score 0):

should be `nextInt()`

```
int sword = rand.nextInt(1) + 1;
int chest = rand.nextInt(9) + 1;
```

`Random` has no `getInt`. See [`Random` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can also use Math.Random(), it will give you a number between 0 and 0.9999....